# How do I used sed -i to edit variable patterns?

Tags: sed

I am using sed to edit some data in a file. And the pattern I am interested in is like this:

```
XXXA
YYYA
ZZZA
```

I just simply wanted to add a `\t` between the A and whatever in front of it. So it will look something like this:

```
XXX A
YYY A
ZZZ A
```

Because the XYZ is different in each file, and I don't want to sed each one of them thousands of times. So I thought I could use `...` as the pattern to represent whatever in front of the A.

So I this is what I've tried:

```sh
sed -i 's/...A/...\tA/' myfile.txt
```

But it changed the `XXXA, YYYA, ZZZA` to `"... A", "... A", "... A"`.
So I am wondering is there any way that I can use sed to do this, and keep whatever in front of the `A` the same??

Help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to capture the 3 characters and use a back-reference in the replacement pattern :

```
sed -Ei 's/(...)A/\1\tA/' myfile.txt
```

In this command `()` around a part of the search pattern defines a capturing group whose content you'll be able to refer to, either in the search pattern to make sure there is the same content at two places, or in the replacement pattern in order to repeat part of what you matched.

The `\1` in the replacement pattern is a reference to the first capturing group (in our case, the only one we defined).

I'm using the `-E`RE regex flavour in order to avoid having to escape the grouping parenthesis, but `sed -i 's/\(...\)A/\1\tA/' myfile.txt` would have been equivalent.

In addition you might want to add anchors in order to make sure you replace a whole line and not part of a line that happens to contain `A` after three other characters :

```
sed -Ei 's/^(...)A$/\1\tA/' myfile.txt
```

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/IM8Aja).

Answer (score 0):

*"I just simply wanted to add a \t between the A and whatever in front of it."* Then here we go:

```
sed -i 's/A$/\tA/' test.txt
```